# Is air drag approximately the same on both a smooth ball and a tennis ball?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag

I am writing a project about projectile motion in 2D at a high school level to the point where I only know the simple drag equation.  The experiment I did was firing a tennis ball with a compressed air cannon. The tennis ball purposely has the hairy "felt" to delay flow separation but if the tennis ball is very used and the hairs barely stick out anymore, would that then mean I could consider it to be a smooth sphere in terms of shape?

I'm asking this because I am confused about if I can apply the same theoretical concepts of air drag on a sphere to a tennis ball. 
I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMmNKUlXXDs&) about air drag and I have not ever had classes or learned about air drag in terms of fluid dynamics/mechanics, so I am not very knowledgeable at all on the topic or any of the calculus related equations.

In addition to this, can I also determine the drag coefficient with Reynolds number like in this graph if I assume the tennis ball is basically a smooth sphere? 
[image]

Comment: web says R is around 85,000.....right near the dip: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jst.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how accurate your calculation needs to be and what Reynolds number you're working with.  Looking at that plot, it seems that assuming a rough sphere is equivalent to a smooth sphere is a good approximation up to $R_e \approx 10^5$.  You should calculate an order of magnitude estimate for the Reynolds number of your system and check whether it falls in the regime where the smooth and rough spheres have similar drag coefficients. I would use the diameter of the tennis ball as the characteristic length scale and its velocity as the velocity to calculate $R_e$.  I think that so long as its not going faster than ~100 km/hr you should be fine approximating it as smooth.